# Libreria: phpseclib uso del get (Descarga local)

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

Tengo un problema con la descarga de los archivos (get), tengo montado xampp en linux y alli esta corriendo mi aplicativo, todo funciona bien MENOS donde se descarga el archivo.

Es decir,voy a otra maquina en red y abro mi aplicacion desde alli, y al momento de descargarse el archivo, en vez de descargarse en mi **carpeta de descargas local**, se esta descargando en la **carpeta descargas del servidor**.

Agrego mi código:

Tengo un formulario html que pide ingresar una fecha:

```
<form action="enviar.php">
   <input type="date" name="fecha">
   <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

luego formateo la fecha a formato YYYYmmdd y voy a buscar el archivo a un ssh y uso la libreria **phpseclib**

```
if(isset($_POST['fecha']) && $_POST['fecha']!=null){ //valido la fecha

    $fecha = date_create($_POST['fecha']); 
    $fecha = date_format($fecha,"Ymd");
    echo $fecha; //formateo la fecha a YYYYmmdd 
    
    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('111.111.111.111'); //IP de prueba
    if (!$sftp->login('root', 'pass111')) { //hago la conexion
        exit('Login Failed'); 
    }else {
        $rutal="/home/usuario/Descargas/"; //la ruta local donde quiero descargar mi archivo
 
        if($sftp->get("/dato/facturas/factura_$fecha.xlsx", $rutal."factura_$fecha.xlsx")){
            //Traigo el documento remoto a mi ruta local, pero no se descarga de manera local si no que se va al servidor.
            echo "OK";
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
Apenas empece a utilizar esta libreria no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre la misma.
**¿Como puedo hacer que se descargue de manera local?**

Saludos.
```